# Analyzing json using Watson API Nodejs

Tags: json, node.js, web, ibm-watson, tone-analyzer

I would like to analyze a JSON file I dynamically create with Watson's tone analyzer. I would like it to read the file, then analyze it.

How can I make the tone_analyzer.tone method read the file? Thank you.

```
app.get('/results', function(req, res) {

    // This is the json file I want to analyze
    fs.readFile('./output.json', null, cb);

    function cb() {
        tone_analyzer.tone({
        // How can I pass the file here?
                text: ''
            },
            function(err, tone) {
                if (err)
                    console.log(err);
                else
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(tone, null, 2));
            });
        console.log('Finished reading file.')
    }
    res.render('results');
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Your callback is missing a couple of arguments (error, data) (see [the node fs documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_file_options_callback) for more info). Data is the content of your file and would go where you are sending the text.

Try something like this:

```
app.get('/results', function(req, res) {

    // This is the json file I want to analyze
    fs.readFile('./output.json', 'utf8', cb);

    function cb(error, data) {
        if (error) throw error;
        tone_analyzer.tone({
        // How can I pass the file here?
                text: data
            },
            function(err, tone) {
                if (err)
                    console.log(err);
                else
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(tone, null, 2));
            });
        console.log('Finished reading file.')
    }
    res.render('results');
})
```

Comment: I made `var data = fs.readFile('./output.json', null, cb);` and passed `data` on the callback function, but it still outputs `error: 'No text given'`

Comment: @agomez That is not going to work, because fs.readFile doesn't return anything.  If you see my code above, I added the data argument to your callback, cb.  There I send the data directly to the tone analyzer.  Also, you may need to add that 'utf8' option to the readFile.  You could also add a variable called text in your route, and separate the tone analyzer from the readFile function.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Aldo, I added my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to user Aldo Sanchez for his tip. I converted the input into JSON first since fs was returning it in the form of buffer data. Also, I made it search for the specific value in the key/value pair and return that content, instead of returning the whole string. This can be directly inputted to Watson's tone analyzer.

```
var data = fs.readFileSync('./output.json', null);

    JSON.parse(data, function(key, value) {

        if (key == "message") {
            cb(value);
        }

        function cb(value, err) {
            if (err) throw err;

            tone_analyzer.tone({
                    text: value
                },
                function(err, tone) {
                    if (err)
                        console.log(err);
                    else
                        console.log(tone);
                });

        }
        console.log('Finished reading file.')
    });
```